# Parsing Google Fonts METADATA.pb - google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, protocol-buffers, google-fonts

I'm trying to parse a METADATA.pb file from the official Google Fonts repo which can be found here: https://github.com/google/fonts (Example METADATA.pb file for the Roboto font: https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/apache/roboto/METADATA.pb)

To parse proto-buf files, the right format is required. It can be downloaded as "public_fonts.proto" here: https://github.com/googlefonts/gftools/blob/master/Lib/gftools/fonts_public.proto

I used it to generate a Python code file called "fonts_public_pb2.py" with this command:

```sh
protoc -I=. --python_out=. fonts_public.proto
```

And here is my code which imports this generated file, reads the content of a METADATA.pb file (shouldn't matter which one, they all follow the same structure) and then tries to parse the proto-buf string.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python

import fonts_public_pb2

protobuf_file_path = 'METADATA.pb'
protobuf_file = open(protobuf_file_path, 'rb')
protobuf = protobuf_file.read()

font_family = fonts_public_pb2.FamilyProto()
font_family.ParseFromString(protobuf)
```

Just a few lines, nothing too complicated, but the output is always the same:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 22, in <module>
    font_family.ParseFromString(protobuf)
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

I don't usually code in Python, so the issue here might very well be me, but after trying a few different things I don't know what to do anymore:

- Used the already generated "fonts_public_pb2.py" file from the gftools repo: https://github.com/googlefonts/gftools/blob/master/Lib/gftools/fonts_public_pb2.py - My generated output from the "public_fonts.proto" file and this file are nearly identical, I check with Meld. The error was still the same
- Set all "required" fields in the .proto file to "optional", Generated the "fonts_public_pb2.py" file again - Same error
- Tried Python 2 and 3 - Same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those METADATA.pb files are not binary protobuf files, they use the [text format](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.text_format).

```py
import fonts_public_pb2
from google.protobuf import text_format

protobuf_file_path = 'METADATA.pb'
protobuf_file = open(protobuf_file_path, 'r')
protobuf = protobuf_file.read()

font_family = fonts_public_pb2.FamilyProto()
text_format.Merge(protobuf, font_family)
print(font_family)
```

Comment: Okay, first: Thank you very, very much, or, because we are both Germans: Danke dir :)

Second: I would not have figured that out on my own, I just assumed that `ParseFromString` requires ... a string!?!

Third: Could you please remove the 'b' from 'rb' in your answer? Here, a "real" string is necessary, otherwise it shows this error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome and gern geschehen. `ParseFromString` does want a string ... of bytes! Certainly not the most obvious method name in the history of method names. I have corrected the code, though it does not seem to make any difference on my machine (Python 3 on macOS).